# sed ignoring triple backticks

Tags: sed, backticks

I want to replace

````
```javascript
something
```
````

with

```
{code}javascript
something
{code}
```

Now, when i run sed on a file with `javascript something`(everything in the same line, no new lines)

````
sed -e 's/```\(.*\)```/{code}\1{code}/' sedfile
````

It outputs what I want: `{code}javascript a23231 {code}`
But when I run sed with a file that has new lines accounted for, it doesnt do it properly.
I tried to espace backticks with \ but it wasnt output I wanted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `sed` operates only one line at a time (based on newline character). There are ways to change that, but `perl` would be better suited if you can have multiple matches in single line (non-greedy matching)

````
$ cat ip.txt
foo ```xyz``` baz ```javascript 123```

```javascript
something
```

$ perl -0777 -pe 's/```(.*?)```/{code}$1\{code}/gs' ip.txt
foo {code}xyz{code} baz {code}javascript 123{code}

{code}javascript
something
{code}
````

- `-0777` to slurp entire input file as a single string
- ```` ```(.*?)``` ```` will match the backtick snippets as minimally as possible
- `{code}$1\{code}` desired replacement, `$1` will have the text matched by the capture group

  - for some reason, `{}` is causing issue in replacement section, which is why the second `{` is escaped. I think it is causing conflict with `hash` syntax
- `s` flag is needed to allow `.` to match newline character as well
- Use `-i` option if you need in-place editing

With `sed` if `-z` option is available and content between the triple backticks cannot have backtick:

````
$ sed -zE 's/```([^`]+)```/{code}\1{code}/g' ip.txt
foo {code}xyz{code} baz {code}javascript 123{code}

{code}javascript
something
{code}
````

The `-z` option causes `sed` to use ASCII NUL as the separator instead of newline character. If input file has NUL character, this solution will not work.

**Edit:** Just realized that a simple ```` sed 's/```/{code}/g' ip.txt ```` may also work if the input is well formed like the example used here.

Comment: thank you for the answer, is it just easier to use perl rather than make sed operate over multiple lines?

Comment: `perl` is more flexible, but `sed -z` can also work if it satisfies the conditions mentioned in the answer

Comment: @PedroGonzalez just realized that `sed 's/```/{code}/g' ip.txt` may also work for you